# Firebase update single document concurrently from multiple devices

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

In my project I have to update field value concurrently from multiple devices and check if the count reaches to 0. When I reduce value of field by 1 then I have make entry in another table. So when I try to update concurrently from 2 devices, the field decrement only by 1 instead of two. And when I tried using transaction, multiple entries are getting added to other table.

Comment: Can you add the code where you are updating this value?

Comment: So the sequence is fetch data from one table(e.g new_mobile_launch) and display on UI. Try to add to cart from multiple devices and add the entry to separate table when you click on add button. So on simultaneous addition app should throw error if item count is reached to 0.

Answer (score 0):

If multiple client need to modify multiple documents concurrently, you'll need to [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions). In this transaction you then `get()` the documents, and write the updates back to the database.

Once you do this in a transaction, the Firestore servers will detect conflicting updates, and force the second client to retry - at which point it gets the correct value (`0` IIRC) and can then alert the user that there's no more stock.

Comment: I tried this solution it leads to multiple entries in second table on addition. Will try once again properly and let you know..

Comment: Transactions are the proper solution for this. If you're having a hard time making them work, I recommend opening a new question with the [minimal code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @puf I want to modify/update the same document from multiple devices at the same time(concurrently)? Is that possible using transaction?

Comment: Hey @AvinashYalgonde. Any update here? Anything else needed?

Comment: @puf In my case I resolved this by adding firebase functions. Unfortunately mobile SDK is not working as expected in my case of transactions.